# Python array shape difference

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, tuples

I have an array as :

```
A
Out[159]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16]])
```

Now if I find the shape of :

```
A[0:1].shape
Out[150]: (1, 8)
```

While, if i try the same for

```
A[ [0,0,1,1], [0,3,2,5] ].shape
Out[151]: (4,)
```

First array seems to be 1 row and 8 columns and the second one seems to be 1 row and 4 columns, then why is the second answer shown as (4,) and not as (1,4) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second case doesn't mean what you think it means.

The way this kind of fancy-indexing works in numpy is as follows: If `A` is a 2dim array and `I1 = [a1, a2, ...]` and `I2 = [b1, b2, ...]` are arrays/lists of ints, this indexing:

```
A[I1,I2]
```

means:

```
np.array([ A[a1,b1], A[a2,b2], A[a3,b3], ... ])
```

`I1` refers to indexes along dim=0, and `I2` refers to the corresponding indexes along dim=1. This means each `[a_k, b_k]` pair defines a single element to include in sliced array.

---

Another way to think about this: think about the tuple returned by `np.where`, and what you expect this to mean:

```
A[np.where(A == x)]
```

Comment: but then what does `Out[151]: (4,)` mean actually ?

Comment: @Sarang it means a 1dim array of size 4.  Since in your case `len(I1)==len(I2)==4`, you "pick" 4 elements from `A`